# Order columns in data frame by list

Tags: r, sorting

Ciao,
Here is my reproducible example.

```
#this is the dataset i have
d <- c(1,2,3,4)
e <- c(7,4,6, NA)
f <- c(9,4,3,6)
g <- c(10,5,4,7)
mydata <- data.frame(d,e,f,g)
names(mydata) <- c("ID","scoreA","scoreB", "scoreC")

#this is the list that i want the columns to be in order by
target <- list("scoreB", "scoreC", "scoreA")

#this is the dataset i want
mydata1 <- data.frame(d,f,g,e)
names(mydata1) <- c("ID","scoreB","scoreC", "scoreA")
```

I have tried many approaches here but can't get this to sort. For example I have tried

```
mydata1 <- mydata[,target]
```

which I know is not correct but I am really stuck here. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I did try this to but target only has the variables score and does not include the id variable, how can i get that back in? thanks a bunch

Comment: `j <- match(unlist(target), names(mydata)); mydata[, c(1, j)]`.

Comment: Excellent for what is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` library to do this sort of operations pretty intuitively. [Here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) you can find more. You can also use `data.table` library ([here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) is the link).

```
library(dplyr)


# if you just want to select "target" columns in order
mydata %>%
  select(ID, target)

# or you can specify column names in the select function
mydata %>%
  select(ID, scoreB, scoreC, scoreA)

  ID scoreB scoreC scoreA
1  1      9     10      7
2  2      4      5      4
3  3      3      4      6
4  4      6      7     NA


# if you want to select and then arrange (sort) data according to order
mydata %>%
  select(ID, scoreB, scoreC, scoreA) %>%
  arrange(scoreB, scoreC, scoreA)

  ID scoreB scoreC scoreA
1  3      3      4      6
2  2      4      5      4
3  4      6      7     NA
4  1      9     10      7

# if you wanto to sort in descending order
mydata %>%
  select(ID, scoreB, scoreC, scoreA) %>%
  arrange(desc(scoreB, scoreC, scoreA))

  ID scoreB scoreC scoreA
1  1      9     10      7
2  4      6      7     NA
3  2      4      5      4
4  3      3      4      6
```